# Bootstrap button onclick not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, ejs

I have a node express app using EJS.

I have a button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="exportWithObjectId('<%= user.id %>')">Export to csv</button>
```

and a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function exportWithObjectId(objectId) {

        console.log("objectID inside .ejs: " + objectId);
    }
</script>
```

in my .ejs file but when I click there is no log.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `document.` from your function call:

```
onclick="exportWithObjectId('<%= user.id %>')">
```

Or, replace it with `window.`:

```
onclick="window.exportWithObjectId('<%= user.id %>')">
```

#### Example:

```js
function exportWithObjectId(objectId) {
  console.log("objectID inside .ejs: " + objectId);
  alert('Just to be sure! objectID inside .ejs: ' + objectId);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="exportWithObjectId('<%= user.id %>')">Export to csv</button>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that was something I tried when it wasn't working.  I originally had without the document.  I edited the post.

Comment: That can't be. I'll add a working example here. The only problem is that you are not including your javascript to your rendered page. What is the exact error in your console?

Comment: no error, nothing.  No console log either.  Just empty, sad clicks.

Comment: Can you add your rendered HTML page to your original question? I added a runable example by copy pasting your code and it works just fine.

Comment: try adding console.log outside the function. Is it working?

Comment: Well, I was about to edit my post with the rendered html when I saw your `alert` code.  I tried that and it worked.  For some reason the console.log isn't working though.  Good to know that the button is.  Thanks.